# MYSQL Get upcoming birthdays (unix timestamp) from Database

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, date

I have a Database table userinfo. In that userinfo-table there are fields user_id, user_name, user_birth.

My goal is to get upcoming birthdays of the users, in my case 6 next ones. I have found examples for same kind of thing but they all have used DATE-dbformat and those examples doesnt work for me because in my table the user_birth values are in unix timestamp-format.

I would appreciate if someone has an examplecode for that how it would be possible to make.

The result what I have tried to get out would be something like(when today is 23.06):

- 27.06 Mike
- 11.10 Steve
- 23.10 John
- 25.12 Dave
- 07.01 Andy
- 12.02 Mark

Those would be the next 6 birthdays after 23.06, year should not matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, use `from_unixtimestamp()` to get it in a date/time format.  So, the query would be something like this:

```
select *
from t
order by (case when month(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))) = month(now()) and
                    day(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))) > day(now()) or
                    month(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))) > month(now())
               then 1 else 0
          end) desc,
         month(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))),
         day(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth)))
limit 6
```

The first part of the `order by` puts later dates in the year first.  Then dates are ordered by month and day of month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer/example Gordon. I have fixed your query a bit that it worked correct by me.

The Problem that comes with the query is that it gives out correct birthdays only till the end of the current year.

So in my case it works correct till "25.12 Dave", but after that when it jumps to next year the sorting is not anymore working correct.

Is there maybe some easy way to fix that?

Comment: @user2514055 . . . It should be working for wrapping around the end of the year.  Can you put up a SQLFiddle with some data showing the problem?